# How to fetch and show pulse rate in android watch face

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

How to fetch and show pulse rate in android watch face.

In the context of an Android watch face, I aim to present the user's heart rate (pulse rate) without necessitating runtime permissions.

Comment: The question is currently very broad, and you will most likely not get a satisfying answer. Please show us what you tried so far (code samples are great!) and focus on a specific problem that you are trying to solve (e.g. not getting any data in X, app is crashing when I do Y).